# MySQL как получить данные полей а не их наименования

Tags: mysql, триггер, процедуры

Пожалуйста подскажите как получить данные, а не наименования столбцов.
Делаю триггер before - update, который сохраняет в теневую таблицу изменения из основной - выглядит так

```
INSERT INTO s_sys (time_edit, guid, edit_string)
VALUES (old.time_edit, old.guid, (
        SELECT CONCAT('old.', (
              SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', old.')
              FROM information_schema.columns
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'sys'
                              )
                     )
                                )
       );
```

Пожалуйста помогите получить данные полей а не их заголовки

Comment: Запрос из INFORMATION_SCHEMA должен собрать не просто список имён полей, а текст запроса на получение значений. Затем этот запрос выполняется через prepared statement, а его результат пишется в таблицу лога.

Comment: пожалуйста опишите подробнее - у меня ругается на PREPARE, говорит мол динамический скул,. пробовал запускать процедуру через call в триггере тоже самое

Comment: Не обратил внимания, что это триггер. Но если так, то он оперирует данными определённой таблицы, структура которой известна - нафига, спрашивается, в INFORMATION_SCHEMA лезть?

Comment: Хорошо опишу задачу по другому есть две таблицы - боевая (скажем sys) и теневая (скажем s_sys) при этом количество полей (как и их названия) в боевой неизвестно но не меньше 5, а количество полей в теневой всегда 3 как организовать триггер на логирование записи теневую таблицу. Скажем если это реализовывать в firebird так это просто песня, в MySQL сплошные слезы

Comment: *количество полей (как и их названия) в боевой неизвестно* Вот эта фраза мне совершенно непонятна. Ты делаешь триггер на эту таблицу - кто мешает посмотреть структуру?

Comment: @Akina, пожалуйста покажи как из SHOW FIELDS IN sys; получить конкретно Field, как сделать group_concat и как присвоить полученную строку переменной. Пожалуйста помоги мне

Comment: *как из SHOW FIELDS IN sys; получить конкретно Field* Глазами посмотреть. И в код занести. Вы пишете триггер для таблицы, структура которой ИЗВЕСТНА. Вот и используйте эти знания. А когда изменится структура таблицы - изменится и текст триггера.

Comment: @Akina, Повторяю я пишу триггер для таблицы структура которой НЕИЗВЕСТНА () имеется только пять стандартных полей остальные (до ста) меняется пользователем регулярно (удаляются, добавляются, меняются параметры) (+2 поля, -1 поле, +3 
 поля, -1  поле - - не строки - столбца) и в таком темпе каждые 20 минут

Comment: Динамический SQL не допускается в функциях и триггерах. Он разрешён в процедурах, но процедура, вызываемая из триггера, имеет те же ограничения, что и триггер - т.е. в такой процедуре динамический SQL также запрещён. В описываемых условиях поставленная задача мне кажется нерешаемой, ибо, как я понимаю, заставить пользователя отказаться от изменяющих данные запросов и выполнять все операции хранимыми процедурами также невозможно.